# Script stopped working after adding posts with pagelime

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, blogs

I have a script that will make the index page only display the 5 most recent blog posts (handeled by it's cms-repeat class). It works fine, until I use PageLime (online light CMS) to add new blog posts (It just duplicates an article that you then edit). For some reason, somemthing PageLime does kills the script and I cant figure out why. I grabbed my html off the server to have a look, but still don't see anything that is preventing the script from running.

Here's the main body section, footer, script code:

```
 <section class="wrapper blog-page">
        <article id="editableBlogPost-1" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix">
    <h2>Paper Towl Rolls</h2>
    <p>text...</p>
    </article><article id="e24450" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix cms-previous-repeat-item-id-editableBlogPost-1" style="display: block;">
    <h2>No Storytime today!</h2>
    <p>text...</p>
    </article><article id="e15438" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix cms-previous-repeat-item-id-editableBlogPost-1" style="display: block;">
    <h2>New Resources for Families</h2>
    <p>text...</p>
    <p><img id="e42608" src="/cms-assets/images/512037.optimized-may12-2-1.jpg" alt="Image of new books at the Logan Family Center, Anxiety, depression, self-esteem and shyness" width="300" height="224" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<img id="eca5c2" src="/cms-assets/images/107497.optimized-may12-1.jpg" alt="Photo of new family resource books, Anxiety, depression, self-esteem and shyness" width="300" height="224" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </article><article id="e3c688" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix cms-previous-repeat-item-id-editableBlogPost-1" style="display: block;">
    <h2>Around the World Presenters</h2>
    <p>text...</p>
    </article><article id="e70d96" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix cms-previous-repeat-item-id-editableBlogPost-1" style="display: block;">
    <h2>Do You Have What it Takes?</h2>
    <p>text...</p>
    </article><article id="e2016e" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix cms-previous-repeat-item-id-e70d96" style="display: block;">
    <h2>Ready! Set! School! -&nbsp;<span>Let's Read!</span></h2>
    <p><span><img id="e91bf1" src="/cms-assets/images/169742.optimized-april15.jpg" alt="Image of Ready! Set! School! Books used in the Lets Read lesson" width="300" height="225" />text...</span></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </article><article id="e30bb5" class="cms-editable cms-repeat clearfix cms-previous-repeat-item-id-e2016e" style="display: block;">
    <h2>Welcome back</h2>
    <p><img id="e5597d" src="/cms-assets/images/287627.optimized-april8.jpg" alt="Image of Ready! Set! School! student with book, everybody counts lesson" width="300" height="225" /><span>text...</span></p>
    </article>
       <input type="button" id="more" value="More">
      </section>

      <footer class="page-footer">...</footer>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script>

    //display next 5 blog posts when "#more" is clicked
           size_article = $('.cms-repeat').size();
            x=5;
            $('.cms-repeat:lt('+x+')').slideDown('slow').show();
            $('#more').click(function () {
              x= (x+5 <= size_article) ? x+5 : size_article;
              $('.cms-repeat:lt('+x+')').slideDown('slow').show();
              alert('its working?');
            });


      //hides "Please enable javascript" message for those with javascript
          $("#no-script").hide();

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that PageLime added the style="display: block" as inline CSS to most of my articles, which of course had higher specificity than my script. I couldn't find anything about turning off inline styles with Page Lime, so I'm just adding another bit of jQuery before the other in order to remove the style attr first.

```
$('article').removeAttr("style");
```